# Displaying plots in the same workspace

Tags: r

I am trying to display the first boxplot horizontally in the first row, the two scatter plots in the second row and lastly the two vertical boxplots in the third row. How can I better my code so that it displays the plots the way I want to?

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1,
                2, 3, 
                4, 5, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=5)

boxplot(calories, data = cereal, horizontal = TRUE,  main='Boxplot of Calories of Cereals')
plot(calories, fat, main='Calories vs Fat of Cereals', xlab="Calories", ylab="Fat", las=1)
plot(calories, protein, main='Calories vs Protein of Cereals', xlab="Calories", ylab="Protein", las=1)
boxplot(fat, data = cereal, las=1, xlab="Fat", main='Boxplot of Fat of Cereals')
boxplot(protein, data = cereal, las=1, xlab="Protein", main='Boxplot of Protein of Cereals')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the design of `layaut` this should work

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,5), nrow=3,ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))
par(mar=c(4,4,3,3))
set.seed(1)
cereal = data.frame(calories = rnorm(15,378,10), fat = rnorm(15,0.9,0.02), protein = rnorm(15,7,1.3))
attach(cereal)

boxplot(calories, data = cereal, horizontal = TRUE,  main='Boxplot of Calories of Cereals')
plot(calories, fat, main='Calories vs Fat of Cereals', xlab="Calories", ylab="Fat", las=1)
plot(calories, protein, main='Calories vs Protein of Cereals', xlab="Calories", ylab="Protein", las=1)
par(mgp=c(1,1,0))
boxplot(fat, data = cereal, las=1, xlab="Fat", main='Boxplot of Fat of Cereals')
boxplot(protein, data = cereal, las=1, xlab="Protein", main='Boxplot of Protein of Cereals')
```

[image]